# How to remove a part of translucent PNG?

Tags: transparency, png

Hard to describe what I need help with... probably better telling the situation that I am in.

[image]

This is an image I want to edit. It is PNG, and some part is transparent, some translucent and some opaque.

I am looking for a method/function that allows me to remove the blue glowing chicken and safely get the blue ring behind it.

It doesn't matter if it does not edit perfectly, as long as it looks better, faster and more accurate than hand-editing.(this is a frame of a GIF, so I don't want to do edit all of them by hand...)

I have another image that might be useful:
[image]

Please help.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but there's no actual, clean way of doing it.Especially if you are looking for a function that does it for you.

You would be better off redrawing the ring.

**PS:**

After seeing that on the ring is actually a repeating pattern, I realized that with a little copy > paste > rotate to match pattern you could get a pretty decent result.

You still have to paint a over the drawing a little bit, erase the center and add some inner shadow but this is what I came up with in like 5-10 minutes of tweaking :

[image]

With a higher resolution image and more time and effort you could do great.

Comment: Right, I figured that out by trial and error with different layer styles and filters. I was thinking more of the filter similar to Greenfish(the one that removes background), but it doesn't really work because the chicken and the ring are in same colour.. :P Thanks for the note!

Comment: @GuardianAngel I've made an update to my answer, there may be a faster and easier way of doing this.